# How to import gis shapefiles into postgis database programatically?

Tags: java, postgis

How can I import gis shapefiles into postgis database programatically using java ?
I used a program named postgis shapefile import but now I want to do it in my java code.

Comment: osm2pgsql is a command line tool for that, maybe doing a batch execution of this via bash is an option for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common tool (one of several) is [shp2pgsql](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#shp2pgsql_usage), which comes with PostGIS. It is normally used from a command prompt, but can be used through Java's [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

```
ProcessBuilder pb =
   new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "shp2pgsql my.shp | psql -d mydb");
Process p = pb.start();
```

[ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) is another commonly used tool to convert most geospatial vector formats to PostGIS.

Comment: thanks for your answer,
shp2pgsql has many options when we work with its gui.
How can I pass this parameters in command?
I searched all available parameters but I can't find any of them inside those parameters.

Comment: @Obtice the gui does the same as the command, which is [well documented](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#shp2pgsql_usage)

Comment: thanks a lot,
could you please explain what "/bin/sh" and "-c" is ?

Comment: It depends on what OS you have. If you have Linux or Mac OS X, this process the command that has a pipe | character with `/bin/sh` (i.e., see `man sh`). But if you have a different OS, you will need to set up the ProcessBuilder differently.